# When is initAutocomplete() being invoked? javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, modularity

Im new to Javascript and I'm playing with googlemaps api autocomplete
functionality.  When I run the code in the browser, it works totally fine as
expected, however I'm wondering when/how these functions are being executed? I dont see where any of them are being invoked, yet it seems like they just work w/o  being invoked.  Whats going on?

Also, how can I modularize this code in a larger web application, wrap all of it in a function? Thanks very much!

```
<script>
  // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
  // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.
  // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
  // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
  // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

  var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
  }

  function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }

  // Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
  // as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
  function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't see any of them being invoked"? Are you basically asking what a callback is? Regarding modularization, there are many ways to do that.

Comment: For instance, in initAutocomplete(), a listener is set for fillInAddress(). Therefore, i can see how fillInAddress() could be invoked.  However, I do not see how initAutocomplete() is ever invoked. Since i dont know how initAutocomplete is called, I don't know how the functionality is working.  This is my concern.